# Admin on REST how to set path for list elements

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am new in Admin on REST.
my response for `/users` is like on this:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "response": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 298487355,
        "login": "000000000053"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
  "error": "text error"
}
```

how can I set path for `response`: `data`: `[...]` to get list of users?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can customize your restClient. for example I choose to work with `jsonServer` so I have this in `app.js`:

```
import customRestClient from './customRestClient'
const App = () => (
    <Admin restClient={customRestClient('http://path.to.my.api/')}>
```

`customRestClient` actually is [this](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/rest/jsonServer.js) file, I bring it to my source, adjust the imports.

this file is the point that your data comes to and goes from your app to your api.

so in the `convertHTTPResponseToREST` function you simply can check for `resource` and if it was `users` you can access the your data by 
`json.response.data` and return it in `switch`

Comment: yes, it works. i am thank you @pelak. you save my day. and what do you think about a proposal for improvement of admin-to-rest for this feature or it's so easy and it's not worth it?

Comment: You save my day

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pelak a lot.
I just write code base on your answer.

In your custom [restClient](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/6b7f7b99219932c74492d598e663756c74bef05f/src/reducer/admin/resource/data.js) point out path to response data.

```
const convertHTTPResponseToREST = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    const { headers, json } = response;
    switch (type) {
        case GET_LIST:
        case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
            if (!headers.has('content-range')) {
                throw new Error(
                    'The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST client expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
                );
            }
            // IF you just want use with **users** resource.
            if(resource === 'users') {
                return {
                    data: json.result,
                    total: parseInt(
                        headers
                            .get('content-range')
                            .split('/')
                            .pop(),
                        10
                    ),
                };
            }
            return {
                data: json.result,
                total: parseInt(
                    headers
                        .get('content-range')
                        .split('/')
                        .pop(),
                    10
                ),
            };
        case CREATE:
            return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
        default:
            return { data: json };
    }
};
```

Keyword: list in child element, list nest