# How to manage DELETE response status code 204 with admin-on-rest?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm trying to integrate [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) with an api sending a 204 HTTP response without a body on successful DELETE.

So on DELETE I get the error message :

> REST response must contain a data key

I'm using `jsonServerRestClient` and I wonder how could I override this client so it accepts 204 on DELETE and redirects to the list ?

Comment: oh, it's very like on my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854617/admin-on-rest-how-to-set-path-for-list-elements
see answer which written by @pelak

Answer (score 1):

so, if my trivial answer was converted to comment write it more detail.

you can write your own client. add this to App.js

```
import customRestClient from './customRestClient'
```

create `customRestClient.js` and put code from `jsonServerRestClient.js`
there in function `convertHTTPResponseToREST`
you can add

```
console.log(response);
console.log(type);
console.log(resource);
console.log(params);
```

and see that `response` is object that contains code of response.
In case block you can write your own behavior by adding DELETE.
I hope, that it will help you

Comment: @ExsiDev if answer is useful, please, check answer as correct. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update convertHTTPResponseToREST method in your rest client to handle responses for DELETE requests and include a data key (which can just be an empty object).

e.g.

```
const convertHTTPResponseToREST = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    ...
    switch (type) {
        case GET_LIST:
            ...
        case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
            ...
        case CREATE:
            ...

        /* START OF MAGIC */

        case DELETE:
            return { data: { } };

        /* END OF MAGIC */

        default:
            ...
    }
};
```

I believe that redirecting back to the list after a successful deletion is the default behaviour.